# Twilio Autopilot - Field Values are cumulative?

Tags: twilio

I'm exploring Twilio Autopilot. I trained a task with an annotated field to collect the user's first name. However it seems like every time I submit a request to this task, the new first name just gets added to an array. E.g. I have the sample set up as something like:

> Hi there, my name is {first_name}.

If I submit it 3 times like this:

> Hi there, my name is Frank.
>
> Hi there, my name is Bill.
>
> Hi there, my name is Jim.

By the third time, it is submitting an array of [Frank,Bill,Jim] for the Field_first_name_Value request parameter.

Is there any way to configure it so we overwrite the value every time we submit the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the moment, there is no way to configure it so the value is overwritten each time the field is submitted. I've passed this on to the product team as a feature request!